# MySQL searching files by file name, tags, file category and author

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, youtube

I'm doing something like youtube.

How to do searching for file?

My database structure:

Files:

```
ID (PK)
AuthorID (FK)
Name  varchar
```

FileToCategory

```
ID(PK)
FileID(FK)
CatID(FK)
```

TagsToFile

```
ID(PK)
FileID(FK)
Tag varchar
```

1. I would like to let user type something in search textbox and then display him best result according to file name and tags.
2. When user is watching some file I want to show him proposed files list according to file names, tags, category(same as actual file) and author.

How to do that?
I would appreciate any code or natural language explanation how to do that.

EDIT

AD. 1

Something like that works but it does not use file name, how to change it?

```
SELECT f.ID, f.Name, count( t.ID ) AS HowsGood
FROM Files f
LEFT OUTER JOIN TagsToFile t ON f.ID = t.FileID

AND t.Tag
IN (
'lucky', 'wow', 'ninja', 'cat'  -- example of searched words
)
GROUP BY f.ID, f.Nazwa
order by count(t.ID) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.Name
FROM Files a, TagsToFile b
WHERE a.ID = b.FileID
AND (a.Name LIKE '%search%' OR b.Tag LIKE '%search%');
```

Comment: It doesnt work if search has more than 1 word and it shows all results, but they are not sorted from the best to the worst

Comment: If your search has more than one word and you want to consider that as two separate searches you'll need to split them in your application or in your procedure and add more OR conditions.

The IN condition you added is only going to work if the user searches for the exactly same file or tag name. For the Tag is acceptable but I doubt someone is going to search for the exactly file name.